# How to access a service from docker swarm using a docker container not deployed in the swarm?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-swarm

I have a Jenkins and Nexus deployed in docker swarm. Jenkins has a docker configured to access host docker via socket.

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

This setup allows use docker inside jenkins deployed on docker swarm and that is working fine.

I am facing issue however when I am trying to build jenkins pipeline with docker containers and subsequently trying to access nexus repository. Basically swarm with jenkins is deployed inside an overlay network that is not accessible from a container used by jenkins pipeline.

Docker network looks as follow:

```
docker network ls:
...
wzr8yyx6hki1        ci-cd-network   overlay             swarm
..
```

Sample jenkins pipeline demonstrating process:

```
pipeline {

  agent none
  triggers { pollSCM('H/15 * * * *') }
  environment {
    NODE_IMAGE = 'node:6'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        agent any
          steps {
            /*generated with jenkins syntax generator*/
              checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@bitbucket.org:code/project.git']]])
                }
        }
    stage('Static code check (run lint)') {
            agent {
              docker { image '${NODE_IMAGE}' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm run lint:ts'
      }
    }
    stage('Unit Test') {
            agent {
              docker { image '${NODE_IMAGE}' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm publish'

            }
    }
  }
}
```

Container created by jenkins pipeline process cannot access a nexus service within network 'ci-cd-network' used by swarm and containing nexus and jenkins machine. Basically nexus service can be accessed from a another docker service deployed in the docker swarm ('i.e. ping nexus') however cannot be accesses from my 'node' container that is simply run as container separately (not in the swarm)? Any idea how to make nexus service 'visible' to a 'node' container  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the created agent container inside jenkins to the overlay network, and then the containers will be able to communicate with each other.

```
agent {
    docker {
        image '${NODE_IMAGE}'
        args  '--network ci-cd-network'
    }
}
```